# How does this Interac e-transfer scam work?

Tags: canada, scams, transfer

I posted a Craigslist ad for selling iPhone 7. Next day I got a text asking of

> Is this item still available... [NAME OF MY AD EXACTLY AS IT'S
>   SPELLED]

.

So I already was suspicious it's a bot.

Then I replied, yes, it's available.

Next thing I get a text

> Ok, then I will pay you [EXACT AMOUNT] and $150 for shipping it to my
>   destination(Miami at least by the phone number). You accept
>   e-transfer, right? So, I will send the payment now.

It's clearly a scam, but how does this work? Are they going to send the payment, but will tell me they will send me the password to receive it once they get the shipment of the phone? And never really give it to me? Just wondering what else can it be?

**Edit:** This question is not a duplicate because it is specific to how Interac e-transfer works. There is no other questions I was able to find that discuss this.

**More details:** 
When I send money via e-transfer here is how it works:

1. I send some sum of money from my bank to persons **email**. When I do this, I also specify a codeword that I would later tell to the recipient so they could claim money I sent.
2. They receive an email stating they got money from me.
3. They claim the money via the link in the email and they have to use codeword I would tell them via some other way(not email or separate email letter).
4. While still unclaimed, money can be still recalled by the sender.
5. Can not be claimed and will go back to sender if recipient doesn't know codeword.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Interac e-Transfer is not equatable to a money order or a cashier check. An Interac e-Transfer is not a physical instrument, and cannot be reversed. There is a novel aspect to this question not considered in the existing question that is w.r.t. money orders and cashier checks. All of those who voted to close are U.S.-based and this specific Interac electronic transfer mechanism is Canadian (operated by a cooperative venture between multiple Canadian banks).

Comment: That's correct - Interat e-transfer is different from all the above and I found no explanation on scams related to it. Please reopen.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea If I understand correctly, Interact e-Transfer can be recalled assuming receiver has not accepted the money yet.

Comment: You offer something for sale. Someone offers to buy it via what I presume is a common electronic payment method in your country. Why is that "clearly a scam"?

Comment: @Alexus Yes, so, more precisely, in theory it cannot be reversed *once accepted*. How this actually works in reality is, I think, a salient point that may help answer this question.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea In order to accept, the sender of the money must also provide password for the recipient. Without password recipient can't claim the money and they can still be recalled/expired. So my suspicion is they send you money, but tell you that they will send you password when they get the package. And never send you password.

Comment: @Lawrence 1. Someone contacts me via a bot. 2. Offers $150 on top of my asking price. 3. I am in Canada, they are in Miami browsing local Canadian craigslist.

Comment: @Alexus Or, guessing, maybe they send you money (with password), you accept, but the money came from an account that they stole access to and the bank later reverses the fraudulent transfer..?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea That's a possibility, as well, but I believe once sent via e-transfer bank can no longer reimburse you. Interac might.

Comment: @Chris W. Rea. I agree. I've been using e-transfer on and off to buy things off used sites for a year or two now. Today was the first day I got flat out turned away cold from a purchase saying that I was scamming. I came looking for this exact question and if I didn't find it I was going to post it. If i could I would vote to reopen this question. Should people "fear" (use caution) when dealing with e-Transfers (my case: Canada-Canada) and if so what flags do you look for?